# How to make sure that a user doesn't go on a specific page in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am trying to make a website with a login form in php. The login documents that I have are:

`login.html` - is the login form 
`loginproc.php` - is where the data from the form is compared to my database and if a username and password exist in my database, it will take user to `admin.php` 
`admin.php` - is the admin section.

What I want to do is if the user puts in the URL `index.php?page=loginproc`, I want the user to be redirected to `index.php?page=login`. I have tried to do this with the code below.

```
else if ($_GET['page'] == 'loginproc' && !isset($_SESSION['username']))  {
        header("Location:index.php?page=login");
        }
```

My login form `index.php?page=login` should be able to go to `index.php?page=loginproc` but I want `index.php?page=loginproc` to be accessed when the user logs in not any time else.

Comment: Use sessions (better choice) or cookies to store user logged credentials after user is loged. Then you can check if they are set. Here is one example: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

Comment: And also there is similar question in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531044/creating-a-very-simple-1-username-password-login-in-php

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "index.php") === false) {
   exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set in header or the area which is called on every page

```
$page = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$user = $_SESSION['session_token'];
$userRole = $_SESSION['session_token_role'];

if($userRole != 'adminId'
&& $page != 'policy.php'){
    continue;
}
```